# Language grammar correction with supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language-processing

I want to work on automatic grammar correction using machine learning (possibly using recurrent or deep neural networks). The algorithm will be supplied with both corrected and initial documents for supervised learning.

I am now looking for some survey or research papers to start with. I have searched and downloaded tens of articles but none of them seems related.

- I would appreciate if someone could provide a few good starting points (papers, books).
- also I suspect that I am not using the correct keywords for my search. I'll appreciate if you could also suggest suitable search keywords.

Answer (score 1):

The following paper from 2011 proposes a nice approach for using language modeling to do grammar correction, as well as an evaluation framework.

- Park and Levy, *Automated whole sentence grammar correction using a noisy channel model*. In *Proc. 49th Human Language Technologies*, volume 1, pp. 934–944. Association for Computational Linguistics, 2011. (Available from the [ACM Digital Library](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2002590).)

Comment: Welcome! It would be nice to give a brief summary of the method to make your answer a little more self-contained.